# What is the French tongue-twister?

Tags: culture

In Godard's Detective at [1:25:18](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HbBLcgouE1CieloFhBN1vgwh1KeDTPwa/view?usp=sharing) and [slower version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnOFbU1MCxhN0JS8kWsTll1hGjG8y4LR/view?usp=sharing) and [extremely slow](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nzc8XcTTabT8f_wLHLs-VtuqnR21ylv1/view?usp=sharing)

one of the characters utters extremely rapidly a French tongue twister which was translated as:

> My kid'll fix your kid so she never calls my kid again.

I could only hear the words 'gamin' and 'rendent' in it. Does anyone know what it is.

####### UPDATE

the actual clips are now uploaded

###### UPDATE 2

now I have an even slower version and I also can sort of make out what they're saying:

si ta gamine (dis?) à ma gamine, ma gamine (prendre?) ta gamine (de sort?) que ta gamine pour appui ta gamine à ma gamine.

Comment: "My kid'll fix your kid so she never calls my kid again." Looks like an enigma

Comment: You might want to post a rough phonetic transcription of what you hear.

Comment: Can't find it online without paying. Maybe you could clip the audio of that one sentence?

Comment: see update ....

Comment: the word is "gamine" (female kid)

Answer (score 1):

> *Si ta gamine dit gamine à ma gamine, ma gamine prendra ta gamine de sorte que ta gamine pourra plus dire gamine à ma gamine*.

Comment: Tanks (pun intended), I really appreciate that.